# Changing log4net file name at runtime without changing the appender

Tags: c#, .net, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I'd like to change the name of my log at runtime without changing the appender. Basically, once it gets to a certain set time of day I'd like to be able to use a different file.

This is what my appender looks like:

```
<appender name="info" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
   <file value="logs\" />
   <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd'_INFO.log'" />
   <staticLogFileName value="false" />
   <appendToFile value="true" />
   <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
   <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
   <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
   <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
     <conversionPattern value="%newline[%date]-%level-%logger[%M]- Linea:%L - %message%newline"/>
   </layout>
   <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
     <param name="LevelMin" value="INFO"/>
     <param name="LevelMax" value="INFO"/>
   </filter>
 </appender>
```

This is the function where I iterate through the appenders:

```
   public void SetLogFile(string fileName)
   {
       foreach (var appender in log.Logger.Repository.GetAppenders())
       {
           try
           {
               ((log4net.Appender.FileAppender)appender).File = fileName;
               ((log4net.Appender.FileAppender)appender).ActivateOptions();
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
           }
       }
   }

   SetLogFile("log1.txt");
```

Which creates the following file for this specific example:

> log1.txt20171221_INFO.log

I'd like for my log file to be named `log1.txt` and not have the `datePattern` set in the `log4net.config` file concatenated with the name, but I can't figure out how to do it without changing the `log4net.config` appender configuration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you are using RollFileAppender, you have to change the RollingStyle and set the path accordingly.

```
foreach (var appender in log.Logger.Repository.GetAppenders())
{
    try
    {
        string file = Path.GetDirectoryName(((log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender)appender).File);
        string filename = Path.Combine(file, fileName);

        switch (((log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender)appender).RollingStyle)
        {
            case log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Date:
                ((log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender)appender).RollingStyle = log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Once;
                break;
            case log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Composite:
                ((log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender)appender).RollingStyle = log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Size;
                break;
        }
        ((log4net.Appender.FileAppender)appender).File = filename;
        ((log4net.Appender.FileAppender)appender).ActivateOptions();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {}
}
```